# Pipe psql timing to file

Tags: postgresql, performance, performance-testing

I am currently using `\timing on` to do some simple performance testing in Postgres.  I would like to run many queries and pipe the timing results to a file.  However, all of the options I have tried (`\o`, `\l`, and their command-line equivalents) pipe only the *query results* to a file.  The `Time: 1.234 ms` message is not written to the file.

Is there any way I can pipe the timing output caused by `\timing on` into a file, or will I have to choose some other method for performing my tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by piping the query into `psql`, then grepping the output, like so:

```
postgres@winterspring:~$ cat foo.sql
\timing on
select * from foo;
postgres@winterspring:~$ psql < foo.sql | grep "^Time:"
Time: 0.505 ms
postgres@winterspring:~$
```

Redirect just the timing to a file if needed:

```
postgres@winterspring:~$ psql < foo.sql | grep "^Time:" >> timing.txt
```

The grep will have a slight performance impact.

Comment: This pretty much is what I ended up doing.  I didn't use grep, though; I ended up silencing all other output with `\o /dev/null` (to eliminate results) and `\set PROMPT1 ` (to set the prompt to the empty string) in my `.psqlrc` file.

Comment: To enable timing for all your `psql` sessions, run this in your shell (note the double backslash): `echo '\\timing on' >> ~/.psqlrc`

Answer (score 3):

The shell function `**time**` would be an alternative solution on Linux / Unix systems.
To append test results to a file:

```
postgres@db:~$ /usr/bin/time -a -o foo psql event -c 'select 1' > /dev/null
```

You may need more connection options.
Discard the actual output of psql with `> /dev/null`.
Use the fully qualified path because - I quote `man time`:

> Users of the bash shell need to use an explicit path in order to run
>   the external time command and not the shell builtin variant. On system
>   where time is installed in /usr/bin, the first example would become
>               /usr/bin/time wc /etc/hosts

`-o` to provide an out file name
`-a` to *append* to the file instead of replacing.

Comment: I wanted to avoid `time` if possible, since I was afraid timing a `psql -c 'SELECT ...'` command might return significantly different results than getting timing results from within an already-running `psql` query prompt using `\timing`.  I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: @apsillers: There is an overhead for starting up psql and connecting to the db, of course. The example with the "empty query" `SELECT 1` above can give you an estimate for how much that is. For extended testing, your final solution better is smarter, though.