# Set 'timing on' for the duration of the current `psql` session using command-line options

Tags: postgresql, scripting, psql, command-line, timing

What is the equivalent of `\timing on` command in `psql`, using the `psql` command-line options? I am aware that this will enable timing for all `psql` sessions:

```sh
echo '\\timing on' >> ~/.psqlrc
```

I am executing an SQL file, and I am looking for an option that looks like these options below:

```sh
psql -h server -U user db -v ON_ERROR_STOP=ON --echo-all -P 'null=NULL' -f file.sql
```

**Related:**

- [How to set 'timing on' permanently in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/156015/192715)
- [How can I time SQL-queries using psql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3148/192715)
- [Pipe psql timing to file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/21509/192715)
- [How can I time SQL-queries using psql from command line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/73270/192715)
- [How to use \timing in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593723/how-to-use-timing-in-postgres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the -c option and the -f option together.  The -c must come before if you want it processed before the file is.

```
psql ... -c '\timing on' -f file.sql
```